# c++ aggregation, passing parameters

Tags: c++, oop

I am new to c++ so will appreciate your help.

The question is how should the constructor of my second class (B) look like if i have this in my main function:

```
B B1(A(1,2),A(3,4),A(5,6));
```

so i have two classes

```
class A
{
public:
    A(float x=0, float y=0): _x(x),_y(y)
    {}

    A(const A & o) 
    {
        _x=o._x;
        _y=o._y;
    }

private:
    float _x,_y;
};
```

And the second class:

```
class B
{
public:
    B(????)
    {
    }
    ~B()
    {
    }

private:
    A *_pPoint;
};
```

Edit:

I want it to save the points into something so i can use them later.

Comment: What do you think?.. Post your thoughts.

Comment: The leading underscore convention is likely to lead to trouble with C library implementation names. Better use a trailing underscore.

Comment: The raw pointer member `A* _pPoint` is presumably meant to point to a dynamically allocated array. As shown the code does not take proper care of copying such, or disallowing copying. Double deletions and other nasty Undefined Behavior is likely to ensue; use a `std::vector` instead.

Comment: B(const A& p1, const A& p2, const A& p3) should work to allow the above call. I may be missing the point here though...

Comment: The answer really depends on what you need to do with the constructor. Could you please clarify?

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf The second class is just an idea about how it should look like(Just my thoughts).

Comment: @batbrat I want it to save the points into something. I tried this before: B(const A& p1, const A& p2, const A& p3), but how if there are more than 3 points?

Comment: @irQ92, you could pass a std::vector<const A&> (more than three points of input - arbitrary number) instead and store it in another vector (arbitrary number stored). The const part is to promise that you won't modify the input. If you want to do that, then you can drop the const. The reference is to stop copying of A objects. If they are very light, you can probably drop them. That's one way to do it...

Comment: @irQ92: OK. if you want to save them, then take them as by-value arguments in the constructor, and `move` them into a `std::vector` (just as a generally good habit). Please update the question with this information about the intent.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf thnx man ^^

Answer (score 0):

Since the constructor is passed arguments of type `A`, it can be -

```
B(A p, A q, A r);
```

Comment: Or it can be `B( A const& a1, A const& a2, A const& a3 )`. Plus many other variants. But the choice between this one and the one in this answer depends on what it's intended to do.

Answer (score 0):

The declaration of the constructor could look as

```
B( const A &, const A &, const A & );
```

As for its definition then it is difficult to say something definite. For examole pPoint can point to a memory region allocated for an array or for a single element.